# Как выбираются сообщения для публикации в Twitter?

Tags: поддержка

Обнаружил, что у StackOverflow на русском есть [свой Twitter](https://twitter.com/ruStackOverflow). Там есть несколько категорий вопросов и ответов: хорошие неотвеченные вопросы, хорошие ответы, даже почему-то вопросы из Меты.

Очень интересно узнать а как выбираются сообщения для публикации в нем? Это скрипт или человек выбирает? Каковы критерии?

Comment: Подписался. Теперь там два подписчика)

Comment: Ответ можно получить на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183410/339911). Желающие сделать перевод - Welcome!

Comment: @alexolut Сделано. Не прошло и двух лет.

Comment: @Squidward не понимаю, зачем так торопиться...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Перевод "[How does the twitter bot work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183410)")

Если понаблюдать за твиторами [Server Fault](https://twitter.com/ServerFault) и [Super User](https://twitter.com/Super_User), можно заметить, что они твитят каждые 3 часа. Согласно [ответу Ника Кравера](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94593), используется алгоритм "популярности", основывающийся на количестве просмотров за отрезок времени, также проверяется, что оценка вопроса не меньше 1 и на нём не висит голосов закрытия, если только не объявлен конкурс (также [согласно Нику](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115899)).

В списке [всех сайтов Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/sites#oldest) ссылки на твиторы, если они есть, отображаются под числом вопросов на сайте.